# Enhance gap between analytic and interpolated data in visualization

Tags: data-visualization, interpolation, matplotlib

I have two data sets, disposed in a 3Dplot. one set represents the interpolated data, the other the analytic. Each set lies on a separate grid.

I have plotted the data with python matplotlib on a linear scale for each dimension.

The problem is that it is difficult to appreciate the difference between the two sets.

What is the best scale to adopt in order to enhance gap between interpolated and real data?[image]

Comment: Add a second plot that shows the differences between the two?

Comment: I'd prefer to keep just this plot, maybe applying  some multiplier to the data?